# Excel Interop or VSTO: Set a Background Image for a Range?

Tags: excel, interop, vsto

I cannot find how to do set a background inside a Range (not inside a Worksheet, thats easy)...

Any magician around ?

Jean-Marie

Comment: Pretty sure there is no way to do this in Excel. There's only `SetBackgroundPicture` - that does not have any options beyond specifying the file to use, and will auto-tile the image.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality does not exist in Excel.  There are a couple of workarounds, although neither will do exactly what you want.

1. Insert the image into the worksheet, and then insert text boxes with the same width/height as the cells in a grid over the image to "simulate" using a picture as a background image.  This is *not* the same as inserting a picture "into a range," as you will lose the ability to address these psuedo-cells.  However, you could programmatically create a two-dimensional array of such textboxes and reference them using the array indices.
2. Insert the picture as the worksheet background, and cover all cells outside the range where you want the picture to be visible with a solid background color.  Excel automatically auto-tiles the background over the entire sheet.  As a result, there are a couple of ways to manipulate Excel into displaying the image only in the range you want.  The drawback of this option is that 
   you can only place a single image in a single location on each worksheet.

   - If the target range is in the top-left corner of the worksheet, you can easily use a solid fill on all cells starting at the right and bottom edges of the image.
   - If the target range is elsewhere in the sheet, determine the exact offset from the top-left corner of the workheet.  In an image-editing tool, expand the size of the image such that the image width and height exactly equal this offset.  Position the actual image at the top-left of this larger image, and leave the enlarged "frame" blank.  When you set the modified image as the worksheet background in Excel, it will place the actual image at the location in which you would like to display it.  You can then hide all replications of the image by setting the cell background for the rest of the sheet to a solid color.

Again, neither of these options answer your question exactly, but as the functionality you are seeking is not supported by Excel, this may be as close as you can get.